# Using Full information maximum likelihood for missing data in R

Tags: r, lme4

I am using the lme4 package to create a hierarchical model for my data. I need to use FIML to handle missing data. Is that possible using the lme4 package or with any other package in R? I have seen this question ([link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51006/full-information-maximum-likelihood-for-missing-data-in-r?rq=1)) that asks the same thing, but it is 10 years old. So, I was wondering if there has been an update since then.

Comment: Can you be more specific about why you *need* to use FIML to handle missing data (rather than e.g. doing multiple imputation)? Is this a requirement imposed on you by a supervisor or a standard in your field or ... ??

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the answer. In the pre-registration of our study, we had written that we would use FIML to deal with missing data. Unfortunately, I didn't (and still don't) have a strong enough background in statistics to have known any better. It is not a strict requirement, but following the analysis plan mentioned in the pre-registration is generally preferable. Can you please tell me if what I'm trying to do is absurd in any way, or is it just not preferred or ...?

Comment: I don't think it's all absurd to do analysis with FIML. I just don't think it's available for general mixed models, and I'm 99.9% sure it's not available for `lme4` models specifically.

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks, we have decided to use multiple imputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** I'm not aware of an easy/off-the-shelf way to use FIML with mixed models as implemented by `lme4`.

`library("sos"); findFn("mixed FIML")` finds only a handful of packages, mostly geared toward specific use cases/designs (item response theory [`mirt`], meta-analysis [`metaSEM`], structural equation and twin modeling [`umx`], etc.); the [mixed model task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MixedModels.html) doesn't have anything on the subject (although suggestions would be welcome!). As mentioned in the linked question, `lavaan` is still a possibility. As the linked question also suggests, Bayesian methods are a reasonable option, and the [brms package supports in-model imputation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_missings.html) (essentially the Bayesian analog of FIML) — although the author of that package himself says that in-model imputation is a bit tricky and he prefers to do multiple imputation, e.g. via `mice` ...

If you want to use `mice` + `lme4` you can start with [this vignette from the merTools package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/merTools/vignettes/imputation.html) ...